# How to use Snakemake with Singularity in largly scaled MPI-runs with SLURM

Tags: mpi, slurm, snakemake

I am working on a CFD-Workflow with snakemake. I want to show other scientists in my field, that reproducible work is possible. The workflow obviously needs to work on cluster systems with parallelized jobs.

Usually SLURM is the jobscheduler we are using. As far as I know I am supposed to use local MPI-installations to work with the singularity container. But as I only can define what is executed inside the container, I cant work with multinode jobs, which means the workflow is not worth that much right now.

the rule that i am struggling with:

[NTRFlows cfd snakemake workflow rule "execute" (MPI, singularity & snakemake)](https://gitlab.uni-hannover.de/tfd_public/tools/NTRFlows/-/blob/main/workflow/rules/execute.smk)

```
rule execute:
    input:
        pfile=f"results/touchfiles/{paramspace.wildcard_pattern}.preped",
        prepedcase = [f"results/simulations/{paramspace.wildcard_pattern}/processor{pid}/constant" for pid in range(config["processors"])]
    output:
        resfile=temporary(f"results/touchfiles/{paramspace.wildcard_pattern}.res"),
        results_pressurefield= protected([f"results/simulations/{paramspace.wildcard_pattern}/{file}" for file in ntrflow.resultfiles["pressurefield"]]),
        results_temperaturefield= protected([f"results/simulations/{paramspace.wildcard_pattern}/{file}" for file in ntrflow.resultfiles["temperaturefield"]]),
        results_velocityfield= protected([f"results/simulations/{paramspace.wildcard_pattern}/{file}" for file in ntrflow.resultfiles["velocityfield"]]),
        results_densityfield= protected([f"results/simulations/{paramspace.wildcard_pattern}/{file}" for file in ntrflow.resultfiles["densityfield"]]),
    params:
        casedirs = f"results/simulations/{paramspace.wildcard_pattern}",
    log: f"logs/{paramspace.wildcard_pattern}/execute.log"
    container:
        "docker://openfoamplus/of_v2006_centos73"
    threads: config["processors"]
    shell:
        """
        (
        touch {output.resfile}
        cd {params.casedirs}
        set +euo pipefail;. /opt/OpenFOAM/setImage_v2006.sh ;set -euo pipefail;
        mpirun --oversubscribe -n {threads} rhoPimpleFoam -parallel 
        ) 2>&1 > {log}
        """
```

As you can see i am calling mpirun from inside the container here. that makes --oversubscribe necressary. also that is why nodes cant communicate with each other.

Questions: does anybody use a singularity container with multinode mpi jobs with slurm-management in snakemake? Any idea how this could work?

I need snakemake to call SLURM-jobs for the shown rule with singularity on multiple computing nodes in MPI